# Marked Items for delete/remove in EFcore don't commit after foreach loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

so I have a list of entities that I am doing modifications in a **foreach**.

Some of the tables I cannot use cascade delete so I need to go into it and do a

```
context.Remove(object)
```

that being said, this works if I do a **context.SaveChanges()** right after this but the performance is slow (this functions is part of a thread to remove objects that are 3 months old).

How ever, when I let the forloop run its course and I save the changes outside it its like it doesnt work at all and my data isnt deleted.

My assumptions where that efcore kept a list of tracked items to process. maybe I am missing something.

here is a sample of the code

```
 foreach (var stop in stops)
 {
                   // I load all data before hand 

                    context.Remove(stop.Recipient.Address);
                    //context.SaveChanges();

                    context.Remove(stop.Recipient);
                    //context.SaveChanges();

                    foreach (var item in stop.Items)
                    {
                        if(item.ShipFromId != null)
                        {
                            context.Remove(item.ShipFrom);
                            //context.SaveChanges();
                            context.Remove(item.ShipFrom.Address);
                           // context.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
  }
                context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That code looks fine.  Set breakpoints and examine the change tracker to see what's going on.

Comment: There is method `context.RemoveRange(manyItems)`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft cool ill take a look at that, that is found in the context or in the direct object?

Comment: @Eldho yeah im using that method lower for the actual stop section. I dont think this would work on this case cause i need to go through each one and set it to delete, Im sure I can prob write a linq query to optimize it

Comment: DbContext https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.changetracker?view=entity-framework-6.2.0